# Orthogonal projection of a conic onto a plane

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, projection

It is well known that conic sections are the intersections of a plane with a cone.  Let the cone be $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$ and the plane be $z = ex + b$.  Project orthogonaly the resultant conic onto the $xy$ plane (projecting both up and down).

I conjecture that the projection of a non-degenerate conic (even a parabola or hyperbola) is an ellipse, but cannot prove this, or find a way to have Wolfram Alpha or similar display this visually.

1. Is my conjecture correct?
2. Is there a way to visualize this?
3. What about degenerate conics? Clearly the point obtained for $b = 0$ projects to a point.  What about other degenerate conics?

Comment: The projection onto a plane not parallel to the plane of the conic gives you a linear transformation. Whatever shape you project is compressed along one axis while its size along a perpendicular axis remains unchanged. What do you think happens to each type of conic?

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is eliminate $z$ from the system cone-plane. Specifically, you get
$$
(ex+b)^2=x^2+y^2
$$
or
$$
(e^2-1)x^2+2bex-y^2+b^2=0
$$
Therefore, the type of the resulting conic-projection depends on $e$. If $|e|>1$ you get a hyperbola, if $|e|=1$, a parabola and, if $|e|<1$, an ellipse.

This is geometrically obvious. Just observe that when $|e|=1$, your plane is parallel to one of the generators of the cone.